# Create .JSON file for local authentication on my Windows 10 PC

Tags: authorization, credentials

I have created .JSON files for 2 PCs so that the user can be authenticated for running Text-to-Speech and Speech-to-Text from Google cloud.  However suddenly on the 3rd PC the generated .JSON file does not allow authentication for some reason.   There is a Google file, (not a user file), _default.py, which fails on the line
info = json.load(file_obj) which fails in the def routine "load_credentials_from_file).

This

I have examined the settings in the Google Cloud and, rebuilt the .JSON file using the Google selected method, reviewed the Environmental variable setting for Google_Application_Credentials. No change.  Conversations with Google Support have led nowhere.